# Strange Field Describe Issue. Not showing existing fields. May be bug?

Tags: describesobject, bug, describefieldresult

We have created an object  last two months ago which contains 6 fields and they all are visible by describe call.

Now we moved that object to another org with all dependencies etc. But there in describe results it is showing only 4 fields but in actual there must be 6 fields.

However those fields can be viewed in object detail page, layout etc. But only in `describe` we can not see . Even if I `describe` like

```
Custom_Object__c.Field__c.getDescribe();
```

I am getting variable not exist `Field__c`.

What can prevent the field to be accessible in describe? Is this a bug or configuration problem? Organisation is Summer 14.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using getDescribe()? e.g. Custom_Object__c.Field__c.getDescribe() ?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Oh thanks! I meant `getDescribe()`.

Comment: have you check the field accessibility ?

Comment: Yes field is accessible.